# Regex to match the nearest character backwards

Tags: java, regex

I have this string:

```
P.1           P.2                    P.3                   P.4  
          ASTON VETERINARY HOSPITAL                                       
            Page 1/2   
        00 PennelJ Road  
      Media, PA 19063-5983 
          (610) 474-5670           
Client :
```

I want to get the text in between `Client` and `P.\d`. Here is the demo:  [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/hYdCB2/1)

```
(P.\d)[\s\S]*(?=^.+Client :?)
```

The problem is that it matches from the first Page `P.1`. I need the nearest `P.\d` before Client.

How to change the regex so that it would match from `P.4`.

Comment: You should be able to use a non-greedy wildcard, ie `*?`

Comment: Get to the last `P\.\d` on the line with `.*`  (or in the string with `[\s\S]*`) and capture what you need. E.g. `.*(P\.\d)([\s\S]*?)(?=^.*Client )`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hYdCB2/4)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't want anything before `P.4`.Is there any way for that?

Comment: Yes, I already gave you that solution: capture the text you need to obtain. Do you see the red-highlighted text at regex101? It is in `matcher.group(2)`.

Comment: You could try a negative lookahead to assert that P.digit does not occur anymore `(\bP\.\d)(?![\s\S]*P\.\d)[\s\S]*(?=^Client :?)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Muw8sj/1/)

Comment: @Thefourthbird Its not working.Will you show me a demo?

Comment: You might use something like http://rextester.com/VISK67749 Did you check Wiktors solution? That also gives you your desired result.

Comment: Just post the code you have if you want a quick and reliable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this with non-greedy operators but that's not going to work. I'd try to move away from having the *entire* regex match precisely what you want, and use groups instead. Then you can just write a matcher to match any number of those `P.1` constructs, and it makes your scan for the `Client` string at the end a lot simpler because you don't have to try to do it as a lookahead. Thus:

```
String x = "P.1  P.2    P.3   P.4 foobar  Client :";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((P\\.\\d)(.*(P\\.\\d))*)+(?<result>.*)Client");
Matcher m = p.matcher(x);
System.out.println(m.find());
System.out.println(m.group("result"));
```

Seems to produce precisely what you want. The syntax `(?<whatever>REGEX HERE)` is regular-expression-ese for: Let me grab just this bit later by asking for the group 'whatever'.

Comment: I'd avoid patterns like `(.*(P\\.\\d))*`. This type of nested quantifiers does not agree with system performance.